# Broadcast a message from server to android phone

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I am sure that this question is asked may time here.

I have an android app which is installed on more that 1K devices. Now i want to implement a functionality where I will send some broadcast message to some selected clients.

If someone can help.

More on this.

1. App is running on a device
2. Server got some updates for some client and sends notification
3. devices receive notification message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement Push Notification for the same. See:

http://blog.boxedice.com/2010/10/07/android-push-notifications-tutorial/

Comment: Thanks Jitendra, Any Ways I have implemented this using C2DM for now.
Can anyone explain me cons of using C2DM.